# Convert form into SearializeObject

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to get the generate the array from the keys.

In the below field the pattern returns keys name-field, row, "".

How to generate the multidimensional array and save the value?

```
 var fixed = [], 
 var pattern = { key: /[a-z0-9_-]+|(?=\[\])/gi }
 var field = { name: "name-field1[row1][]",value :"10" }
 var keys = field .name.match(patterns.key), k;
 //returns name-field, row, ""
 while ((k = keys.pop()) !== undefined) {
 if(fixed[key] === undefined) {
    fixed[key] == []
 }                       
  var obj = []
  obj[k] = pair.value;      
  fixed[key] = obj;// I am doing wrong saving in the "row" key I need save in "col"
 }
```

output:

{ name-field : row1 { [10 , 20 ,30],row2:[20,30,40] } }

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question .

I need to convert the form into objects.

Here is link of the [code](https://gist.github.com/blpraveen/9759682) which serialize the form to an objects

```
var push_obj = [];
if (patterns.push.test(keys[(keys.length - 1)])) {
    $(keys).each(function(i,val) {
        if(i == (keys.length - 1)) return false;
        if(jQuery.inArray( val, keys ) == 0 ) {
            if(named[val] === undefined) {
                return false;
            }
            push_obj = named[val];
        } else {
            if(push_obj[val] === undefined) {
                push_obj = [];
                return false;
            } else {
                push_obj = push_obj[val];
            }
        }
    });
}
keys.reverse();
$(keys).each(function(i,val) {
    if(patterns.fixed.test(val)){
        var obj = [];
    } else {
        var obj = {};
    }

    if(jQuery.inArray( val, keys ) == 0 ) {
        if (patterns.push.test(val)) {
            push_obj.push(pair.value)
            obj = push_obj;
        } else {
            obj[val] = pair.value;
        }
    } else {
        obj[val] = prevObj;

    }

    if(jQuery.inArray( val, keys ) == (keys.length - 1)) {

         named = $.extend(true, named, obj);

    }               
    prevObj = obj
});
```

Comment: You can accept your own answers. Please do so, so this can be considered as resolved